# ListView not updating the recently added entries in JavaFX

Tags: listview, javafx, observable

I run into this issue a while ago and though I found my way around solving it, I'm still curious as to why my first implementation didn't work. In a `ListView`, selection changes, additions and removals work as expected. Updates though work only for the initial entries of the list and not for the ones I add later.

Let's say I have a ListView of books that is created with an `ObservableList` as the source. I add a selection change listener and a `ListChangeListener` to monitor additions and updates with the use of a `Callback`. Initially the ObservableList is populated with some books. When I alter any of these entries (e.g. modify the title of a book) the ListChangeListener fires as expected, and the ListView reflects these changes.

The Book class:

```java
public class Book {
    private IntegerProperty id;
    private StringProperty title;

    public Book() {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        this.title = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }

    //ID 
    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(int id) { 
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    // TITLE
    public String getTitle() {
        return title.get();
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty titleProperty() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Book other = (Book) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, other.id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title.get();
    }
}
```

and a main class for testing the issue:

```java
public class ListViewTest extends Application {
    private ObservableList<Book> bookList;
    private int tmpIdSeq = 100; // temp autogen ID for testing

    private ObservableList<Book> createBookList() {
        // create the callback for updates
        Callback<Book, Observable[]> extr =
                (Book b) -> new Observable[]{
                    b.idProperty(),
                    b.titleProperty()
            };
        // create the list of books
        List<Book> tmpList = new LinkedList<>(); 
        // add a few books
        for (int i=2; i<6; i++) {
            Book b = new Book();
            b.setId(i);
            b.setTitle("Citadel " + i);
            tmpList.add(b);
        }
        ObservableList<Book> startList = 
                FXCollections.observableList(tmpList, extr);
        // return the observable list
        return startList;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // setup the UΙ
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        HBox btnBar = new HBox();
        Label statusLbl = new Label("");

        // create the ListView using the observable list
        bookList = createBookList();
        ListView<Book> listView = new ListView<>(bookList);

        // add a selection listener
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    // prints current & previous  selection
                    statusLbl.setText("Curr: " 
                            + (newValue != null ? newValue.getTitle() : "<None>")
                            + ",  Prev: " 
                            + (oldValue != null ? oldValue.getTitle() : "<None>"));
                }
        );         

        // add a change listener to the observable list of the ListView
        bookList.addListener(
                (ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Book> change) -> {
                    String txt = "list changed";
                    System.out.println(txt);
                    while (change.next()) {
                        if (change.wasPermutated()) {
                            // not implemented
                        } else if (change.wasReplaced()) {
                            // not implemented
                        } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                            // not implemented
                        } else if (change.wasAdded()) {
                            txt = txt + ", wasAdded";
                            System.out.println("added new");
                        } else if (change.wasUpdated()) {
                            txt = txt + ", wasUpdated";
                            System.out.println("updated");
                        }
                        statusLbl.setText(txt);
                    }
                });

        // create sample buttons: add & update
        Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
        btnAdd.setOnAction((ActionEvent ev) -> {
            // adds a new entry in the list
            Book b = new Book();
            b.setId(tmpIdSeq);
            b.setTitle("The " + tmpIdSeq++);
            bookList.add(b);
        });
        Button btnUpdate = new Button("Update");
        btnUpdate.setOnAction((ActionEvent ev) -> {
            // modify the title of the selected book
            Book b = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            b.setTitle(b.getTitle() + " I");
        });

        // showtime
        btnBar.getChildren().addAll(btnAdd, btnUpdate);
        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, btnBar, statusLbl);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); 
        primaryStage.setTitle("ListView Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    } 
}
```

When I hit the Update button in any of the intial "Citadel *n*" entries, the listener fires and the ListView shows the change. When add a few more "The *n*" entries with the Add button, select one of them and hit the Update button, the listener does not fire and the ListView does not get updated unless I scroll away, add more entries, or otherwise manually refresh it.

Using a debugger, it seems that the newly added entries have a null helper, while the original ones have a helper with a listener attached.

The problem is resolved when I use an `ArrayList` instead of a `LinkedList` to make the ObservableList. It also works fine when I use `FXCollections.ObservableArrayList` instead of `FXCollections.ObservableList` as follows:

```
private ObservableList<Book> createBookList() {
        // create the callback for updates
        ...
        // create the list of books
        ObservableList<Book> startList = 
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(extr);
        // add a few books
        for (int i=2; i<6; i++) {
            ...
            startList.add(b);
        }
        // return the observable list
        return startList;
    }
```

So, I wonder why the LinkedList doesn't work eventhough I have the Callback etc. Do I really have to use ArrayLists in some way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not looked at this in detail yet, but your `Book.equals()` method looks wrong. `return Objects.equals(this.id, other.id);` should be `return Objects.equals(this.getId(), other.getId());`

Comment: Which doesn't fix the issue. This looks like a bug?

Comment: @James_D, ok. Left the IDE autoinserted one for the example. I actually check the primitive int in the original project. Not affecting the outcome though.

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug. `FXCollections.observableList(list, extractor)` checks if the list is an instanceof `RandomAccessList` (`ArrayList` is, `LinkedList` isn't), and if so delegates to [`ObservableListWrapper`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/collections/ObservableListWrapper.java). If not, it delegates to [`ObservableSequentialListWrapper`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/collections/ObservableSequentialListWrapper.java). ...

Comment: In the former, the `doAdd()` method attaches a listener to the properties defined by the extractor; in the latter, it doesn't.

Comment: The issue mentioned by James is not the only thing regarding the `equals` implementation that I'd reimplement: The `id` property is modifiable which means that equality could change over time. Let's assume you insert 2 books into a set that uses only `equals` to determine the presence of duplicates and after that modify the id; you end up with 2 non-equal elements but a set containing only one of them. Usually dou don't base `equals` on a mutable property unless you have full control about the kind of context `equals` is used in.

Comment: while we're talking sets: Now that you've implemented `equals`: `hashCode` now violates the contract: 2 equal elements could have a different `hashCode`s. You need to change the `hashCode` implementation in a way that calculates the result solely based on the id; in this case simply returning `getId` would work... However this makes the fact that the `id` can be modified even worse: Insert an element into a `HashSet` (or similar data structure relying on `hashCode`) and modify the `id`. You'll be extremely lucky to be able to find the element again...

Comment: @fabian thanks for the comment. Please note that this is a minimal example only. In the original project IDs are generated in a unique manner and the logic behind the `equals` stands. As for the `hashCode`, it seems irrelevant to the issue so I didn't included it in the example. It's implemented properly as you suggest.

Comment: as @James_D already noted: dynamic extractor handling in ObservableSequentialListWrapper is definitely completely broken (does neither remove nor add on modifications) Nothing to do but re-implement (or not use a linked-list) and report a bug :)

Comment: Really the whole design looks wrong to me... It's based almost entirely on inheritance. The extractor functionality should be implemented using a decorator on an existing observable list.

Comment: @James_D yeah, probably - we could wrap a custom TransformationList around the observableList and implement the extractor on the level of the TransformationList.